# Command code . in zsh - I don't see any files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

when I create a new project, a folder and I would like to access this place with the code command . I do not see any files or contents. If I open VS Code and then open a folder with VS Code then I have all the contents and if I later use the code . command everything is ok, but when using a new folder, project, the same thing happens again. Would anyone be able to advise what could be the cause? (I couldn't find any information about this)

[image: Screenshot]

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Is the sub-shell in VS Code running as the same user as your regular shell?

Comment: the error message talks about the parent directory, what is special with that, does it work by choosing bash as your shell, what happens for a different user or location like `/tmp/project`

Comment: @svin83 Yes, for both the user is the same

Comment: @rioV8 It's only for the user, if I choose a different user or location like `/tmp/project/` its completly fine

Comment: Does the user have r+x access to the project directory and all parent directories?

Comment: @svin83 The Documents has `drwx------+` and there are two folders one is `drwxr-xr-x` where the error of permissions appears and second has `@` at the end and this folder I can open with the `code .` command.

Comment: If I open the folder using VS Code, the folder gets an extended attribute with the contents com.apple.macl: